# htaccess RewriteRule redirects to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am really puzzeld, I want to use htaccess Rewrite to rewrite an url with parameter to one without.
This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^sitemap.xml$    sitemap.php    [NC]    # Handle requests for "sitemap"
RewriteRule    ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$   displaycategory.php?category_name=$1    [NC]    # Handle requests for "categories"
RewriteRule    ^items/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$     item.php?category_name=$1&id=$2    [NC]    # Handle requests for "single item"
```

Rule 1 and rule 3 are working fine, but the second url redirects to index.php

If I call this url:

> http://example.de/category/test/

it redirects to

> http://example.de/category/test/index.php

Comment: Is `/category/test/` a real directory?

Comment: no the directory /category/ does not exist

Comment: ok are there more rules in this .htaccess as well?

Comment: no, i posted the whole .htaccess file. I am hosting at all-inkl.comn

Comment: ok what happens when you open `http://domain.com/displaycategory.php?category_name=test` in browser?

Comment: Everything is working normally

Comment: There would have to be something in your PHP code that is causing this redirect. There does not seem to be anything in the htaccess that would cause the browser to redirect.

Comment: There is no rule in the code shown that will redirect to `index.php`. It has to be either some PHP/JS code or some other rule in Apache config (or any other .htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .htaccess rewrite rule is correct, and I assume its not this causing the problem. If you have a directory called test or another file very close to test Apache Multiviews could be the problem. Have you access to server logs? I bet there is something in the server config preventing the rule from working correctly.